# Why there are 5 Versions of Timer Classes in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

Why are there five timer classes in the .Net framework, namely the following:

1. `System.Timers.Timer`
2. `System.Threading.Timer`
3. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`
4. `System.Web.UI.Timer`
5. `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`

Why are there several versions of the Timer class? And what are the differences between them?

Comment: There are actually 4 Timer classes, you're forgetting `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and `System.Web.UI.Timer` (and also `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`, but it has a different name...)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, thank you pointing that out, I updated the question.

Comment: They all behave differently, example System.Threading.Timer spawns a new thread for each time it tick.

Comment: Here you go: Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library https://web.archive.org/web/20150329101415/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx Contents - System.Windows.Forms.Timer - System.Timers.Timer - System.Threading.Timer - Thread-safe Programming with Timers - Dealing with Timer Event Reentrance - Conclusion

Comment: @MitchWheat, I took a look on the question you provided, it discusses only 2 out 5, hence its not a duplicate.

Comment: What about the `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer` compared to the others?

Answer (score 51):

Here's a description of the primary timers and the points that i find to be the most noteworthy.

`Winforms.Timer`

- ticks on UI thread
- ticks delayed until UI thread is idle
- will skip ticks if the UI thread is busy long enough for multiple ticks to pile up

`DispatcherTimer`

- invoked on UI thread
- can set priority for what level of 'idle' is required to generate a tick
- will skip ticks if they pile up

`Threading.Timer`

- ticks on a worker thread from threadpool - no option for specifying thread
- ticks are always fired on time
- none are skipped - you must guard against new ticks while you're still processing a former tick
- *unhandled exceptions will crash the application*

`Timers.Timer`

- wrapper around threading timer
- ticks on a worker thread taken from the CLR threadpool
- can force to tick on a specific thread by supplying a SynchronizationObject
- ticks are always fired on time
- none are skipped
- silently eats exceptions

Comment: *ticks are always fired on time*. Always is a strong word. AFAIK an available thread-pool thread is required for a tick to occur on time.

Comment: Need to update for `PeriodicTimer` in .NET 6.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 12):

`Timers.Timer` generates an event after a set interval, with an option to generate recurring events. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Windows.Forms.Timer` is a Control for winforms.

`Web.UI.Timer` performs asynchronous or synchronous Web page postbacks at a defined interval. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com//en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Threading.Timer` is the timer for Callbacks. Creates a new Thread for working. Served by thread pool threads. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com//en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, these timers have different purposes, also they are served by different tools.

Answer (score 4):

This question is now answered by Microsoft in the MSDN article for `system.timers.timer`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-5.0

> Tip
>
> Be aware that .NET includes four classes named Timer, each of which
> offers different functionality:

> `System.Timers.Timer` (this topic): fires an event at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service
> component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and
> is not visible at runtime.

> `System.Threading.Timer`: executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is
> defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the
> System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a
> server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it
> has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.

> `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (.NET Framework only): a Windows Forms component that fires an event at regular intervals. The component has
> no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded
> environment.

> `System.Web.UI.Timer` (.NET Framework only): an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a
> regular interval.