# I can't close the program while Task.Delay is running

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that repeats an action (for example a click) every n seconds.
My problem is that while Task.Delay() is running I can't interact with the program at all (the main issue is not being able to close it).

This is the function that I'm using as a timer :

```
private void timer(int time)
{
    var t = Task.Run(async delegate
    {
        await Task.Delay(time);
    });
    t.Wait();
}
```

The way I use it is for example :

```
int x = 10;
while(x-- > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test"); // display a messagebox
    timer(1000);             // 1 second delay
}
```

Is there a better way to delay an action or can I make it work this way?

Comment: **Why** do you have `t.Wait();` in there?

Comment: What you're doing there is just a very convoluted alternative to `Thread.Sleep(1000)`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the delay?

Comment: This might help: [Why there are 5 Versions of Timer Classes in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10317088/1115360)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `Wait` it blocks the UI thread until the task is complete. You will need to remove `Wait` from your code.

You can instead return the task from `timer` and `await` it in the `while` loop. This way the code will run asynchronously without blocking, but it requires you to add async to the method that contains your `while` loop.

There are already built-in timers in .NET framework, you can use one of them instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: He should also remove the Task.Run as it doesn’t really serve a purpose here.