# Why does my timer not stop when checkbox is unchecked?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Here's my code

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            myTimer.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            myTimer.Stop();
        }

    }
```

It should stop repeating the function when unchecked, but it doesn't. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I have one child. I ask them to start drawing. Then I have **another (`new`) child** and I ask them to stop drawing. Did I ever ask the _first_ child to stop? No, no I didn't.

Comment: Use the [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: This code obviously creates a new timer every time the CheckBox state is changed.  Also, based on the text `DisplayTimeEvent`, there are likely UI-thread issues too. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62232924/1563833) for recommended repairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you stop using `System.Timers.Timer` and start using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` component.

1. Begin by removing your `myTimer`-related code (the entire body of `checkBox1_CheckedChanged` will need to be replaced with code from below.)
2. Add a `Timer` component to your form using the designer and name it `myTimer`.  This  will add a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` field to your form called `myTimer`.
3. Using the designer, set the `Tick` event handler of `myTimer` to `DisplayTimeEvent`.  (Or add a new handler and replace its code with the code of your `DisplayTimeEvent` function.)
4. Then change your `checkBox1_CheckedChange` function to look like this:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out int interval)) {
        this.myTimer.Interval = interval;
    }
    this.myTimer.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
    this.textBox5.Enabled = !checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

I also recommend adding the following handler to `textBox5` to perform the bare minimum validation so you can't crash your app by entering an interval of `0` or the empty string, or some text that is not an integer.

```
private void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.checkBox1.Enabled = (int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out int interval) && interval > 0);
}
```

The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`'s `Tick` handler will be called in the UI thread, meaning it will be safe to do things like update labels of your form in that handler.  In contrast to that, the `System.Timers.Timer` will be called on a worker thread and will require that you take on some some thread-management responsibilities you likely don't want to incur, such as invoking your UI updates back to the main UI thread.  See [Why there are 5 Versions of Timer Classes in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime checkbox1 is changed, new Timer is created. When checkbox is ticked, created timer is active and will invoke DisplayTimeEvent forever. When checkbox is unticked, you stop another Timer, which was just created.

You need to create Timer only once (probably when form is created), or when checkbox1 is changed first time:

```
private System.Timers.Timer myTimer;

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myTimer == null) {
        myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DisplayTimeEvent);
        myTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
    }
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        myTimer.Start();
    }
    else
    {
        myTimer.Stop();
    }

}
```