# Timer won't start in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, timer

I have started the timer with `Game.Start()` and by using a breakpoint I have determined that the timer is enabled, the interval is 100. However when stepping through my code, the timer sub is ignored and the paint sub is given priority. Therefore, the timer is never being run.
Here is the code which i am referring to :

```
Public Class Form1
Dim speed_s As Integer = 5
Dim speed_w As Integer = 5
Dim speed_d As Integer = 5
Dim speed_a As Integer = 5
Dim Enemy1 As New computerControlled(1, 1, Me)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    player1.Bounds = New Rectangle(player1.Location.X, player1.Location.Y, player1.Width, player1.Height)


    'Enemy1.DrawEnemy(Me)

    Game.Enabled = True
    Game.Start()


End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        player1.Top -= speed_w
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        player1.Top += speed_s
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        player1.Left -= speed_a
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        player1.Left += speed_d
        ' Enemy1.enemypic.Left += 10 this moves enemy class well
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Game.Tick
    'Enemy1.enemypic.Left += 10
    Enemy1.Walk()
    MsgBox("hi")

End Sub
Private MOUSE_X As Integer
Private MOUSE_Y As Integer

Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    MOUSE_X = e.X
    MOUSE_Y = e.Y

End Sub
Private Sub Player_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles player1.Paint
    Dim GFX As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim BMP As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("c:\firaas\ball.png")
    Dim center As Point = New Point(player1.Width \ 2, player1.Height \ 2)
    Dim angle As Integer
    Dim rad As Double
    Dim CENTRE_X As Integer
    Dim CENTRE_Y As Integer

    '=========================
    Using cyan As New Pen(Brushes.Cyan, 2)

        GFX.ResetTransform()
        GFX.TranslateTransform(CENTRE_X, CENTRE_Y)
        GFX.RotateTransform(angle) ' angle in DEGREES!
        'For Each pos As PointF In pat.Positions
        '        Dim r As New Rectangle(pos.X, pos.Y, 1, 1)
        '        r.Inflate(3, 3)
        '        GFX.DrawEllipse(cyan, r)
        '    Next

    End Using

    '===========================


    Dim rotatematrix As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix()
    Dim srcRect As New RectangleF(64, 64, 64, 64)
    Dim OffsetX As Single = Me.Width / 2 - player1.Width / 2
    Dim OffsetY As Single = Me.Height / 2 - player1.Height / 2

    CENTRE_X = player1.Location.X + player1.Width / 2
    CENTRE_Y = player1.Location.Y + player1.Height / 2

    rad = Math.Atan2(MOUSE_Y - CENTRE_Y, MOUSE_X - CENTRE_X)
    angle = rad * (180 / Math.PI)
    '================================================================================
    BMP = New Bitmap(My.Resources.ball)
    GFX.TranslateTransform(player1.Height / 2, player1.Width / 2)
    GFX.RotateTransform(angle)
    GFX.DrawImage(BMP, 64, 64, player1.Location.X, player1.Location.Y)
    GFX.ResetTransform()

    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(player1.Height / 2, player1.Width / 2)


    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle)

    ' BMP.RotateAt(angle, New PointF(player1.Location.X, player1.Location.Y))


    e.Graphics.DrawImage(BMP, New Point(-player1.Width \ 2, -player1.Height \ 2))


    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(BMP, New Point(0, 0))


    player1.Invalidate()

End Sub
```

End Class

'latest project

Comment: I have tried creating a new timer but the problem persists

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your code. Also, there are [several different timers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10317088/8967612) in .NET. Which one are you using?

Comment: i've updated with code

Comment: Enemy1 doesn't look like it is inside a container. Hard to tell what's going on here: `Dim Enemy1 As New computerControlled(1, 1, Me)`

Comment: once the timer (game) has been started in load, it should load however the timer subroutine is never incremented through. i put a breakpoint in the timer sub and left it for a while and the breakpoint was never triggerd.

Comment: Well, it's hard to help.  We don't see enough code to know.

Comment: updated with whole code, the Sub Player_Paint has been given priority over the timer, can this be fixed?

Comment: `player1.Invalidate()` Don't do this in a paint event.

Comment: I removed the sub player_paint and the timer runs perfectly, is there a way to keep that sub in without it hindering the timer?

Comment: Thanks Lars, removing player1.Invalidate() fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If this is the complete code, it doesn't seem like you're setting your timer's interval.

So you're telling it, it can tick and what to do each tick but not actually setting a time for it to tick.

```
Game.Interval = 60000 '1 minute
Game.Enabled = True
Game.Start() 'I don't believe you need this line
```

Comment: That's not the problem, also the interval is set by default when i created the timer.