# Windows Forms async await

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, async-await

While I using winforms app, each 5 minute I need to check data updates. I need to send request to few service then get response and update data in database. What's is the best practices to make on another thread (or task ?)? The program should not slow down.
I try to make with timer:
Init timer when program is running

```
public class Timer
{

    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private void InitTimer()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
        timer.Elapsed += ElapsedTime;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ElapsedTime()
    {
      //send request and update data
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? [Run async method regularly with specified interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462079/run-async-method-regularly-with-specified-interval)

Comment: It can also be helpful for you: [Why there are 5 Versions of Timer Classes in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias timer with async method, right?

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at Hangfire.

Comment: The `Timer` events can overlap. Using something like the `PeriodicAsync` method is safer IMHO.

Comment: They can overlap, in theory. 5 minutes might be safe.

Comment: When using `System.Timers.Timer`, you're not running on the UI thread, which is good, but you need to invoke the form or control you want to update in the end in order for the UI code to run on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are doing it will work just fine. The [documentation for `Sytem.Timers.Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) says:

> If the [SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject) property is `null`, the Elapsed event is raised on a [ThreadPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread.

The `SynchronizingObject` property is `null` by default, so your `Elasped` event will run on a ThreadPool thread, not on the UI thread. That means it will not stop your application from responding to user input.

If there is a chance that `ElapsedTime()` will run longer than your interval, and you don't want the events overlapping, then you can set [`AutoReset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.autoreset) to `false` and reset it manually at the end of `ElapsedTime()`. Just make sure that everything is wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block, otherwise the timer won't get reset if there's an exception. My code below shows how that would look.

You don't need to use `async`/`await` anywhere here. Since it won't be running on the UI thread, using asynchronous code won't really help you any. In a desktop app, it's not a big deal to have a separate (non-UI) thread wait.

```
public class Timer
{

    private System.Timers.Timer timer;
    private void InitTimer()
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
        timer.Elapsed += ElapsedTime;
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void ElapsedTime()
    {
        try {
            //send request and update data
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log the error
        }
        finally
        {
            //start the timer again
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*In a desktop app, it's not a big deal to have a separate (non-UI) thread wait.*" -- Although this is true, using async/await increases the `ThreadPool` availability, and comes at no tangible cost at performance or convenience (assuming that the programmer is already familiar with the technology), so I wouldn't agree with the advice to avoid it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Normally I'd agree, but using async inside an event handler is tricky since it's `void`. You still *could* make it async, but it makes things a bit more complicated and I just don't think it's worth it. But to each their own.

Comment: Gabriel AFAIK the purpose of [async void](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) is specifically to make asynchronous event handlers possible. So using it for its intended purpose should be OK. A consequence of using `async` in the `Elapsed` handler might be (I haven't tested it) that any unhandled exception will propagate, instead of been swallowed, which is the ["subject to change"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed#remarks) behavior of this tricky event.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Agreed. You could do it either way.