# Queue actions to run when stopwatch reaches a certain exact timespan

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, .net-6.0

I am making a software to show a chronometer on screen and run certain actions at certain times defined by the user. I found a way to show the chronometer on an independent window by using a DispatcherTimer with a 16ms Interval (around 60FPS) but now I have to find a way to run those actions at the defined times.

I made a component `QueueableStopwatch` which does the work. It works in the following way:

- Give it an array of `QueueAction` objects
- Internally creates an array for the QueueActions to be ran once (sorted by interval)
- Internally creates another array for the QueueActions to be repeated
- It have an internal `Stopwatch` to count the time
- The component have the methods `Start()` and `Stop()`
- `Start()` starts the internal stopwatch and starts the "queue processing" loop on a separate thread
- `Stop()` stops the stopwatch and the "queue processing" loop stops by itself when `Stopwatch.IsRunning` changes to false

The "queue processing" loop does the following:

1. Keeps a reference to the next `QueueAction` to be ran. If the internal `Stopwatch.Elapsed` > to the referenced `QueueAction.Interval` its ran and the reference updates to the next one in the run once QueueActions array
2. We run each QueueAction in the to be repeated array under the condition `Stopwatch.Elapsed / QueueAction.Interval - QueueAction.TimesExecuted >= 1`. If ran we increase `QueueAction.TimesExecuted` by one.

Is this solution good enough to be implemented as the "core" of an application running critical actions?

Can the usage of `Stopwatch.IsRunning` end up in unexpected behavior as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile)?

This is the component code:

```
public class QueueAction
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interval to run the action
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// The current action to run
    /// </summary>
    public Action Action { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispatcher the action will be ran into
    /// </summary>
    public Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// True if the action will be repeated
    /// </summary>
    public bool Repeat { get; set; }
}
public class QueueableStopwatch
{
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public TimeSpan Elapsed => _stopwatch.Elapsed;

    private RepeatableQueueAction[] _repeatQueue = { };
    private QueueAction[] _singleQueue = { };

    public QueueAction[] Queue
    {
        get => _singleQueue;
        set
        {
            _repeatQueue = value.Where(action => action.Repeat).Select(action => new RepeatableQueueAction { QueueAction = action }).ToArray();
            _singleQueue = value.Where(action => !action.Repeat).OrderBy(action => action.Interval.TotalMilliseconds).ToArray();
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (_stopwatch.IsRunning)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The chronometer is already running");

        _stopwatch.Start();

        if(_singleQueue.Length > 0)
        {
            new Task(() =>
            {
                int i = 0;
                QueueAction selectedAction = selectedAction = _singleQueue[i];
                do
                {
                    if (i < _singleQueue.Length && selectedAction.Interval <= _stopwatch.Elapsed) // Single time run queue
                    {
                        selectedAction.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => selectedAction.Action());
                        i++;
                        if(i < _singleQueue.Length)
                            selectedAction = _singleQueue[i];
                    }

                    foreach(var repetitionAction in _repeatQueue) // Repeat run queue
                    {
                        if(_stopwatch.Elapsed / repetitionAction.QueueAction.Interval - repetitionAction.Repetitions >= 1)
                        {
                            repetitionAction.QueueAction.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => repetitionAction.QueueAction.Action());
                            repetitionAction.Repetitions++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (_stopwatch.IsRunning);
            }).Start();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _stopwatch.Reset();
    }

    private class RepeatableQueueAction
    {
        public QueueAction QueueAction { get; set; }
        public int Repetitions { get; set; }
    }

}
```

If you want to run it this xaml does the work:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Background="Black">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Name="lblMessage" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="56"/>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    QueueableStopwatch stopwatch = new QueueableStopwatch();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stopwatch.Queue = new QueueAction[]
        {
            new QueueAction
            {
                Dispatcher = lblMessage.Dispatcher,
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(7),
                Action = () => lblMessage.Content = $"[{stopwatch.Elapsed}]I run every 7 seconds",
                Repeat = true
            },
            new QueueAction
            {
                Dispatcher = lblMessage.Dispatcher,
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                Action = () => lblMessage.Content = $"[{stopwatch.Elapsed}]Queued first but ran at 10 seconds"
            },
            new QueueAction
            {
                Dispatcher = lblMessage.Dispatcher,
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                Action = () => lblMessage.Content = $"[{stopwatch.Elapsed}]3 seconds elapsed"
            }
        };
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stopwatch is the wrong tool for the job, you are essentially spinwaiting on a thread, burning CPU time and potentially causing other threads to be starved.

The framework already provides this functionality in the form of [timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net). If you want to run actions on the UI thread a dispatch timer would be suitable. So for each action you want to schedule, create a corresponding timer. You might need a wrapper if you want to decide up front if the action should be repeated or not.

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer(){ Interval =  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
timer.Tick += (o, e) => {
    lblMessage.Content = $"[{stopwatch.Elapsed}]Queued first but ran at 10 seconds"
    timer.Stop();
    };
timer.Start();
```

The resolution of timers depend on the OS, but typically 1-16ms. For a UI program this should be sufficient, there will be various small delays for the screen to render anyway. If you need better resolution there are [mediatimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24843946/12342238).