# I'm confused with the Task.Run(async ()=>await SomeMethodAsync()) and Task.Run(()=>SomeMethodAsync)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core-3.1

It is a bit difficult for me to understand the following asynchronous usage. I have tested them locally and found that the actual result of both of them is the same, but I do not know in which scenarios the two should be used and whether there are potential problems?

The most basic requirement is that there is a property that does something. If true, it will start a thread (without interfering with the current thread) to perform a loop operation, and if false, it will close the loop operation.

```cs
public bool IsMaster
{
    get { return _isMaster; }
    set
        {
           _isMaster = value;

           if (_isMaster)
           {
              if (_httpTask == null || _httpTask.IsCompleted || _httpTask.IsFaulted)
              {
                 _httpTask = Task.Run(async () => await HandleHesApiRequest());
                 Logobject.LogDebug($"[HttpService]Master core,HTTP listenning started");
              }
           }
           else
           {
              while (true)
              {
                  //dispose resource
                 if (_httpTask == null || _httpTask.IsCompleted || _httpTask.IsFaulted)
                 {
                      Stop();
                      Logobject.LogDebug($"[HttpService]Worker core,HTTP listenning stopped");
                      break;
                  }

                 Thread.Sleep(2000);
               }
           }
       }
}
```

The asynchronous method is like this

```cs
public async Task HandleHesApiRequest()
{
    int relayCount = 2;

    while (true)
    {
        if (!IsMaster)
        {
           Logobject.LogDebug($"[HttpService]Changed to worker core,HTTP listenning stopping...");
           break;
        }
        else
        {
            //Do some job whether 'IsMaster==true'
        }

       await Task.Delay(xx)
     }

   Logobject.LogDebug($"[HttpService]Exit service...");

   await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The question is I don't understand the difference between

```
_httpTask =Task.Run(()=>HandleHesApiRequest());
```

and

```
_httpTask = Task.Run(async () => await HandleHesApiRequest());
```

The Sdk is .Net Core 3.1

Comment: `HandleHesApiRequest` seems to be a Asynchronous method, so why you use   `Task.Run`?

Comment: This is the case when [eliding async-await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) is completely justifiable.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep(2000);` is not something what you should do in properties.

Comment: As @GuruStron points out, in this particular case there is no semantic difference, but there is a lot wrong with that code. You should rewrite the entire `IsMaster` property into a method which returns `Task<bool>`. There are also many other problems. It's not exception safe it's not thread safe and it's deeply surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, [it is justifiable](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) in this case to elide the `async` on the delegate, as it doesn't do anything useful.

However, you shouldn't be running such complex stuff inside a setter anyway, and certainly you shouldn't block looping waiting for the task just because it's a setter. Instead make a separate `Set` method that is `async` and `await` the task. this also allows exceptions on the task to bubble up correctly.

Furthermore, your `if` logic doesn't seem right, it seems the logic should be reversed when cancelling. And `IsCompleted` includes `IsFaulted`.

```cs
public bool IsMaster { get; private set; }

public async Task SetIsMaster(bool value)
{
    _isMaster = value;

    if (_httpTask?.IsCompleted ?? false)
    {
        await _httpTask;  // bubble up exceptions
        _httpTask = null;
    }

    if (_isMaster)
    {
        if (_httpTask == null)
        {
            _httpTask = Task.Run(HandleHesApiRequest);
            Logobject.LogDebug($"[HttpService]Master core,HTTP listenning started");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // original logic seems incorrect
        if (_httpTask != null)
        {
            Stop();
            await _httpTask;
            _httpTask = null;
            Logobject.LogDebug($"[HttpService]Worker core,HTTP listenning stopped");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice,my logic in setter is wrong and may cause troubles

Answer (score 1):

- `_httpTask =Task.Run(()=>HandleHesApiRequest());` : It is passing a synchronous delegate to Task.Run, which means that the Task.Run method will return a Task that represents the completion of HandleHesApiRequest.
- `_httpTask = Task.Run(async () => await HandleHesApiRequest());`: It is passing an asynchronous delegate to Task.Run, which means that the Task.Run method will return a Task that represents the completion of the async lambda, which in turn awaits the completion of HandleHesApiRequest.
- The only difference is that in the first one, you're creating another
  async lambda function to generate a Task while your Get method is
  already a Task, so you can use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

For the given example there is no real difference. For a method that *only* calls another method it should make little practical difference if the returned task is awaited or not.

But you should probably use a timer instead. The "Loop around a sleep" is an anti pattern, while the "loop around a Task.Delay" is a bit better, it is probably still not the best way to do it.

Some basic rule of thumb are:

1. If you are doing IO-operations, like reading from disk, or making http requests, use the Async pattern.
2. If you are doing heavy computations, use a background thread, i.e. `Task.Run`
3. If you are doing anything periodically you should use a [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net).

There are cases where you would want to combine patterns, like using async pattern to wait for a slow computation, or a [periodic timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0) together with async code. But that really depend on the specifics, and there is not enough details in the examples to provide any specific recommendation.

I would also recommend reading quite a bit about this topic. Multi threading and async/await are both fairly complicated topics. [Dissecting the async methods in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/dissecting-the-async-methods-in-c/) and [There Is No Thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) are a few good reads, but there are plenty of other good reasources out there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and recommend resource,I also found I need to learn more about it,