# Thread vs async loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, asynchronous

I am trying to change the test1 source code to test2 source code.
Are there any differences between the two source codes?
Which code is more efficient

```
public class Test1
{
    public static Test1 Instance { get; } = new Test1();
    public event EventHandler EventSomething;

    public Test1()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
            EventSomething?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}

public class Test2
{
    public static Test2 Instance { get; } = new Test2();
    public event EventHandler EventSomething;

    public Test2()
    {
        Run();
    }

    async void Run()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5 * 1000);
        EventSomething?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        Run();
    }
}
```

I don't think there is any difference

Comment: Where has `while (true)` gone?

Comment: @shingo second one has "infinite recursion" instead of infinite `while`...

Comment: Do you want to know the difference between `Thread.Sleep` and `await Task.Delay`, or about loop vs recursion? You can't ask both, otherwise your question would be too broad, and might be closed for the reason "Needs more focus".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the results of both codes are the same. However, I am curious about which code is more efficient in terms of hardware usage.

Comment: Like Alexei wrote, the result of the former is an "infinite" loop and the result of the latter is "infinite" recursion. Too much recursion will end with a stack overflow.

Comment: @SmellyCat I needed the part you mentioned. thank you

Comment: I think infinite recursion is bad practice. In this case you don't get a stack overflow because of the async stuff. I'd rather see a while loop over there.

Answer (score 4):

Neither is good.

If you want to do something periodically you should use a [timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317088/why-there-are-5-versions-of-timer-classes-in-net) in most circumstances. That makes your intent much clearer and your code more readable.

When using any timer you need to think about a few things. These are also relevant for your "proto-timers"

1. What thread is used (i.e. UI thread or background thread)?
2. Do you want to include the time to execute the work in the interval or not?
3. Is there any risk of multiple executions to overlap?

Missing from most lists of timer is the new [Periodic timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-7.0) for a "async timer", i.e.

```
while(await myPeriodicTimer.WaitForNextTick()){ // Dispose the timer to exit
    EventSomething?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

With regards to efficiency, most timing related things will use the OS to do the actual timing. There might be differences in overhead between different approaches, but in most cases it just does not matter. If you are really concerned about efficiency you should start by *measuring* whatever parameters you worry about. [Just make sure you measure correctly](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid all waiting inside an loop or recursion and use a timer of some sort.

Here's an implementation using Microsoft's Reactive Framework:

```
public class Test2 : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler EventSomething;
    
    private IDisposable _subscription;
    
    public Test2()
    {
        _subscription =
            Observable
                .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
                .Subscribe(x => EventSomething?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs()));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_subscription != null)
        {
            _subscription.Dispose();
            _subscription = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Just `.Dispose()` of your test class when you're done for proper clean up.